# How do you prevent lynx from unzipping files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip

Lynx has this bizarre behaviour where it (randomly!) decides that a file is a zip file, and then automatically unzips it. This is extremely frustrating: it means it's no longer acting as a web browser and doing the thing it's supposed to (save the file / give me the option what to do).

Googling widely on the topic I can't find docs or explanation for this "feature". Digging in the /etc/lynx config file I can't see anything that's enabling this - and so can't figure out how to disable it. It has a lot of unused options for giving paths to an unzip/gunzip/bzip2 etc - but none of those are active.